# How to add custom field to existing WebSphere portal signup page

Tags: websphere-portal

How to add custom field in existing websphere portal signup page. And where to changes for storing custom field data in database.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to add, ones that are already known to the ldap config can be easily added , go to the edit profile portlet, and configure it to add the other properties via a check box.  if you want custom ones follow this

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/sec_subman.html

As for storing the data, you can either store as part of the user object in a property extension database(so it presents as part of the user object on login)
http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2009/04/configuring-look-aside-database.html

Or you can extend your ldap schema and store it directly there